How do I determine which "Recovery Partition" is being used (or needed) in two different SSDs?
Short summary of recent events I performed on my PC:

Originally, there was only one drive with a Windows 10 installed.
I bought another SSD, installed it in same PC and then installed Windows 11 on it.
Used msconfig to make 11 as default and remove Windows 10 option while starting PC.
Now the new drive (Disk 1) has partition C with Windows 11 and old drive (Disk 0) has become D with old Windows 10 files. I formatted D partition to remove old OS files.

I don't know how the Disk Management state was before doing all of these things, but this is the current state:

This is how it looks in File Explorer:

Now if I'm not wrong, the current OS is still using Disk 0 for EFI and maybe Recovery Partition too. I'm not sure.
There's only one EFI but I see Recovery Paritions exist in both SSDs - 546MB and 642MB.
Microsoft support agent told me to keep them as it is for keep the system working. But I'm not convinced if I need both Recovery Partitions here. For example, before buying new SSD, there was probably only one Recovery Partition.
I could be wrong here. Please correct me if I'm.
So how do I determine which one is needed for the system to keep working and which one can be removed?

The one you need is the one on the same drive of the system partition.


which one is needed for the system to keep working

Recovery partitions are only used for recovery – though potentially also for some major system updates, but I remember Windows would automatically deploy a recovery partition if missing in such situations.

and which one can be removed?

Run reagentc /disable to disable the partition (which moves its contents to a backup location within C:\Windows). After doing so,
a) the partition which has just become empty is the "real" one, whereas the one which still has files is stale;
b) both partitions can now be removed, and you can follow the instructions on creating a new one at the correct location on your system disk, followed by reagentc /enable to move the files back to their correct location.

That seems to be working. I had to use diskpart to remove both of them. The one reagentc /info showed was in Disk 1 though. Now the EFI partition, I don't wanna ask how to move it to Disk 1 here. But is it possible? And is it worth it?

It's possible (Microsoft has instructions for that and you can use bcdboot to fill it from the originals in C:\Windows\Boot at any time), but personally I think it would look ugly if you were to plop it at the end of the disk, so if I was starting with your layout, I'd first use GPartedLive to move the entire C:\ partition some 200 MB rightward in order to make space for the ESP at the beginning instead.

Thanks. Also I'm not sure what size to use for new recovery partition. Would 700MB be enough?
